# Postgres + Node, moved development environment to Windows and having trouble getting authenticated to connect to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

So, I've been developing in Node on my Mac for about a year. I recently got a work computer and want to migrate some things over so I can continue my projects on this (much more powerful) laptop. I am having trouble connecting to Postgres on one of my projects. My connection script is the same and I am connecting to `postgres://localhost:5432/portfolio`. Ports are the same.

I am getting this error on start:

```
 C:\Users\Admin\workspace\personal-page-jade-sass\server\db\connection.js:21
      throw(err);
      ^

error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\Admin\workspace\personal-page-jade-sass\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:539:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\Admin\workspace\personal-page-jade-sass\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:366:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\workspace\personal-page-jade-sass\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:105:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:536:20)
```

I honestly don't remember setting up a password in my old work environment. I've tried setting `pg.defaults.username` and `pg.defaults.password` to nulls and blank strings, but it doesn't help aside from change the username.

Any way to reconfigure the password on the new instance of Postgres that I've installed? This seems like a noobish question but I'm not finding any help on searches.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to log in to the database using psql or pgadmin with the same credentials you're supplying to your application?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Node.js 6.x :)

If so, then such issue was fixed in `node-postgres` 4.5.5

See [the issue that was raised and the fix provided](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1000) ;)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be it. I am still using Node v4.5.0